# Как правильно уничтожить визуальный компонент с использованием события?

Tags: delphi, события, vcl

Создаю свой VCL на базе TScrollBox для удобной работы с множеством последовательностей ДНК.

```
type
  TSeqPanel = class (TPanel)
  protected
    editBtn, delBtn:TButton;
    procedure Resize; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent); virtual;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Resort; virtual;
  end;
  TSeqBox = class(TScrollBox)
  public
    EditAction, DelAction:TNotifyEvent;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent); virtual;
    procedure AddPanel(name,hint:string; tag:integer);
    procedure DeletePanel(tag:integer);
  protected
  private
    panels:array of TSeqPanel;
  end;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фактически `TSeqBox` - контейнер для панелей с кнопками, которые создаются динамически (используется массив panels для хранения объектов). Событию `OnClick` кнопок `editBtn, delBtn` также динамически присваиваются методы из основной формы:

```
   panels[l].editBtn.OnClick:=EditAction;
   panels[l].delBtn.OnClick:=DelAction;
```

В частности, `DelAction`, это:

```
procedure TForm1.DelSequence(Sender: TObject);
var
  l:integer;
begin
   l:=(Sender as TButton).Tag;
   //тут идёт удаление данных ДНК
   seqBox.DeletePanel(l);
end;
```

Добавлю для полноты картины метод DeletePanel и деструктор TSeqPanel:

```
procedure TSeqBox.DeletePanel(tag: integer);
var
  i:integer;
begin
   panels[tag].Free;
   if tag < high(panels) then
    for I := tag to High(panels)-1 do
      panels[i]:=panels[i+1];
   SetLength(panels,high(panels));
   // код для перерисовки панелей 
end;

destructor TSeqPanel.Destroy;
begin
  delBtn.Free;
  editBtn.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Проблема: если я из кода основной формы просто вызываю метод `DeletePanel`, необходимая панель замечательно удаляется без ошибок. Если же посредством нажатия кнопки delBtn на панели через вызов события, то вылезает ошибка c0000005 Access violation. Как я понимаю, кнопка delBtn удаляется вместе с родительской панелью раньше, чем происходит какое-то обращение к какому-то методу этой кнопки или панели.
**Как тогда правильно организовать передачу события на удвление?**

Comment: В последних версиях Delphi есть TThread.ForceQueue - гарантированное "отложенное выполнение", что как нельзя лучше подходит для "удалить себя из своего же метода"

Comment: @kami Действительно, волшебным образом сработало, при минимуме усилий:    TThread.ForceQueue(nil, procedure
      begin
        seqBox.DeletePanel(l);
      end);

Comment: @kami Стоит сделать ответом, чтобы решение заметно было.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Классическая задача вида **"удалить себя из своего метода"**.

Общего решения под все версии Delphi и все поддерживаемые платформы, к сожалению, нет.
Потенциально - наиболее общим можно бы считать аналог решения из ответа @MBo, только использующее вместо прямой отправки сообщения - таймер, но оно в большинстве случаев будет слишком избыточно и громоздко.

Посему, если вы используете последние версии Delphi, то наиболее правильно будет воспользоваться методом [TThread.ForceQueue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Classes.TThread.ForceQueue):

```pascal
TThread.ForceQueue(nil, 
    procedure 
    begin 
      seqBox.DeletePanel(i); // этот код выполнится "когда-нибудь потом", когда приложение
      // будет бездействовать
    end);
```

Однако, здесь есть **подводный камень**, скрывающийся именно в выполнении задачи "потом": если в промежутке между постановкой кода в очередь на выполнение (ForceQueue) и реальным его выполнением объект, содержащий seqBox, будет уничтожен - **выйдет ошибка доступа к памяти**.

Во избежание подобного, при уничтожении формы крайне желательно озаботиться тем, чтобы все поставленные в очередь отложенные выполнения уже выполнились:

```pascal
destructor TForm1.Destroy;
begin 
  CheckSynchronize(0); // здесь будут вызваны и выполнены все участки кода, заявленные
  // на отложенное выполнение через ForceQueue, Queue, Synchronize
  inherited;
end;
```

Если же в вашей версии Delphi метод TThread.ForceQueue не поддерживается (а приложение разрабатывается под ОС Windows) - используйте код из ответа **@MBo** (он лишен указанного выше подводного камня)

Answer (score 1):

Можно послать сообщение родительскому окну, передав tag для идентификации - кого именно убивать. Тогда удаление произойдёт после выхода из обработчика (Post-, не SendMessage)

```
PostMessage(Form1.Handle, WM_USER+666, tag, 0);
```

Пример привёл для формы, т.к. тут легче всего организовать приём сообщений, но компонент должен всё содержать в себе, и обрабатывать эти сообщения от деток сам.

Comment: Спасибо, может, и попробую. Но возни больше, нежели с вариантом, предложенном в комментарии @kami

Comment: Да, конечно. Если не понадобится на старых Дельфях использовать или ещё какой функционал навесить.

Comment: ага, и под Андроид решение с ForceQueue не прокатит.

Comment: Под андроид я с сообщением сомневаюсь, а ForceQueue-то почему не должно работать?

Comment: Сам ещё не проверял, просто наткнулся: http://fire-monkey.ru/topic/4074-tthreadforcequeue-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-android/

Comment: Тогда надо посмотреть, как сейчас работает TForm.Release. Раньше было через сообщение CM_RELEASE, для мультиплатформы могли что-то добавить. UPD: так и осталось

Comment: указанная в топике таска закрыта Эмбой: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17841